# type word on keyboard and be redirected?

Tags: javascript, html

So what I'm trying to do is have it so the user just has to type a specific phase into the keyboard, without having to press enter, or select a text box.

For example, the user types "Fireworks" then is redirected.

Comment: You have to capture general keyboard events, and test to see if they spell out the word, then run a function to redirect. Check the docs for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append each char to a string and check if it is equal to `"fireworks"`, upon which complete the redirect.

```js
var word = "";
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  c = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
  if(c == "f"){
    word = "f";
  }else{
    word+=c;
  }
  if(word == "fireworks"){
    alert("Opening google...");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I threw something together as this may help. But I would suggest editing this as this only alerts. You will need to change it to redirect somewhere else.

```js
var word = "";
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  word += String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (event.which == 8){ //backspace
   word = ""
  }else if (event.which == 0) { //delete
   word = ""
  }
  if (word == "foo"){
   alert(word);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```